# Android App continous receiving data via USB

Tags: android, android-ndk, usb

I'm developing an Android App which i want to communicate with a device connected via USB. This device is delivering data all the time. These data are visible with a programm on the android linux shell.

My goal is to see those data in my App and after that deliver them via a Service to other Apps.

So my question is: Can i "open" a connection from my Android App to the USB-Port so im continuesly receiveing the data in my app, which are sent by the usb-device? And if yes, how would the code look like?

*Edit

Thank you for your answers, the app itself doesn't run on the commandline any more. So its no executable anymore but a shared library getting load by my android app.
It did before, but i want to be able to initiate the connection using NDK methods in my App to be able to see the data in my App itself. So I've tried to see if a connection is allready open.

I've added some functions to my code, so i can see if the usb-connection is open and i have the permission to that usb device.

```
UsbManager.hasPermission(device)
```

returns true, because I'm using an itent filter.

```
UsbManager.openDevice(device)
```

returns an UsbDeviceConnection, so i seem to have the access to use that device.

What im not capable of so far is receiving either iniciating the bus connection to by usb-device and of course either getting data input of that device.

Since my native code allready has a while(true)-method which is only using callbacks to send data to my app when actually data getting sent trough my usb-device i want to keep the work done in my c-code.

The only job my app should do is open the bus-connection once and after that be ready for callback from the c-code.

Is that possible?

Comment: Normally I'd ask if the other end is a "USB device" or a "USB host" but it sounds like you already have a command line tool which works with it, so we can perhaps skip that and I will just ask how the command line tool does what it does.  If there is no device-node-permission issue you can just refactor that tool as a JNI library and run it out of an Android service; if there is a permission issue you will need to start a privileged native daemon and talk to it via linux style IPC.  Or you can create a custom group ID to own the device node and tie it to a custom android permission.

Comment: the device is a CAN-Bus - USB-Device. I need to open the connection once. After that a while(true) method in my c code is using callbacks to send the data to my app. Usually the methods thats doing callbacks is made for just showing the data on the command line.That is working fine if i change my code to an executable. I think its a "usb device" since it's only there for sending the CAN-Bus data via usb to my android device. I'm actually thinking about, if callbacks even need any pemission, or do i only need to give permission to open my CAN-Bus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the app that runs on the command line, you can actually run a command line from within your app.  Take a look at the [Process](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Process.html) class and the [ProcessBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) docs for full details.  The example given is below

To run /system/bin/ping to ping android.com:

```
  Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
       .command("/system/bin/ping", "android.com")
       .redirectErrorStream(true)
       .start();
   try {
     InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
     OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();

     readStream(in);

    finally {
     process.destroy();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe.  But this is rarely the best solution.  There are only a few reasons to resort to it - lacking sources, licensing firewalls, or the most common, needing to run the helper process as a more privileged user ID on a lightly hacked device (with a custom "su" tool) rather than the more involved project of engineering in a way to handle permission for the specific resource.